# How to install GParted in Ubuntu 19.10 at the latest version (>1)?

Tags: gparted, 19.10

When you install [GParted](https://gparted.org/) in Ubuntu 19.10, it installs the old version `0.32.0-2`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gparted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  xfsprogs reiserfsprogs reiser4progs jfsutils kpartx dmraid gpart udftools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gparted
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/482 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,245 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package gparted.
(Reading database ... 212957 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gparted_ ===> 0.32.0-2 <=== _amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gparted (0.32.0-2) ...
Setting up gparted (0.32.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.63ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
```

How to install the [latest](https://gparted.org/news.php?item=233) one, `1.1.0-5`, or, at least any version higher than 1 ?
Command line solution preferred (I mean apt-get or Snap).

*thank you!*

Comment: Having trouble wiping/formating two different SD cards in 3 different adapters in 3 different computers, 2 different OSes, 3 different partition softwares. Maybe and just maybe the new GParted at least tell me where the problem might be. Agreed the fact that is safer to use the given version, but worth a shot.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04 and its default gparted is 1.0. I sometimes have downloaded the gparted ISO to get latest and boot that. https://gparted.org/download.php Shows as 1.1

Comment: You might want to also ask about the problem you are experiencing when trying to format the SD cards. That's the [actual problem that you are trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). To me it would seem more likely that the problem has to do with something on your end.  The extent of the issue you are explaining, if it was a fault with the software, I don't think it would go unnoticed and unpatched.  Have you tried "Disks" for your use case?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: This seems like the common, [classic misunderstanding that many new users have](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) about snapshot-based distros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might really want to see if there is something wrong with the cards, etc first, but in the meantime if you really need the newest version, here you go:

Download the `tar.gz` file from https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted/gparted-1.1.0/

Extract the file

```
tar zxvf gparted-1.1.0.tar.gz
```

Install required prereqs

```
sudo apt build-dep gparted
sudo apt install libgtkmm-3.0-dev itstool build-essential
```

Go to the gparted folder

```
cd gparted-1.1.0/
```

Now run the `configure`, `make` and `make install`:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Now gparted should show the newest version:

[image]