# exfat partitioning, resizing support for 20.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning, gparted, exfat

I have found [Why is exfat greyed out in gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999580/why-is-exfat-greyed-out-in-gparted) in which it is stated:

> For GParted version v1.2.0 and above (Ubuntu 21.10 and above)
>
> exFAT support was added in version 1.2.0 of GParted.

Is there any backported support to LTS for the ability to resize and add partitions to an exfat device (in this case, a CFExpress card accessible through USB -- the gparted in 20.04 can "see" the card, but not manipulate the exfat filesystem)?

Comment: Not at this time (as far as I can tell). Is this something you need regularly? If it’s just an occasional need, perhaps you could make a bootable USB stick of 21.10 and use a live session to resize the partition 

Comment: Presumably 22.04 LTS will have the updated gparted -- when will 22.04 have a production release?  Can I run 21.10 under VirtualBox under 20.04 to gain this functionality, or must I boot into 21.10?  If I do boot 21.10 as a bootable "stick" image on the 20.04 on the 20.04 hardware machine, will anything get corrupted so that 20.04 will not operate correctly once I again boot 20.04 from the machine (not the stick)?  Is the revised gparted available as a snap for 20.04 (theoretically, snaps are self-contained sufficient)?

Comment: How to install GParted in Ubuntu 19.10 at the latest version (>1)? [closed] https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279018/how-to-install-gparted-in-ubuntu-19-10-at-the-latest-version-1 claims to show a method to port the most recent gparted to an older Ubuntu that does not come with the latest release?  Will this work in fact or cause problems due to lack of encapsulation and exposure of incompatible libraries, etc., to the rest of the 20.04 environment?

Comment: for now, I believe that `mkfs` supports exfat via `mkexfatfs`. I could be wrong, but its pretty easy to check. What are you trying to achieve with gparted. There may be another solution.nm just saw the last p of your question. `dd` can do that, but BE CAREFUL! Very dangerous, especially if you are prone to typos like em.   I believe that both of the above cn do it.

Comment: I do not use {dd} for creating partitions.  Again, is there a "current" gparted SNAP?  If not, will the porting method mentioned in one of the replies to a different (but related) query work as explained in that earlier reply, or will it cause problems for 20.04?  If I do this within MS Win 10 under VirtualBox (that can "see" the USB mounted device) under 20.04, is there a MS Win utility (licensed for fee, no doubt) that will do this for exfat (e.g., same or more functionality than gparted)?

Comment: @YashaKarant If you have virtual box, it is entirely possible to install / run any version (within reason) of Ubuntu from within 20.04. Same goes for Docker / containers. If a version can be installed on your device, then it can also be installed to a VM / container running in 20.04 on that same device. You can't run 21.10 or 22.04 from any device because they are not released yet. For Ubuntu Desktop, the version numbers are also the release dates. If gparted is a snap then yes. You can usually add --edge to get the "nightly" stable or --beta to get the, well, beta.

Comment: On windows you have PartDisk, which is more or less the same as gparted (for our current purpose anyway.) It is a command line tool, and not sure if it supports exfat but I would guess so. Comes with win10 by default.